# Tkinter Performance Issue on macOS - Lag on Internal Display but Not on External

Tags: python, tkinter

**Details:**
Tkinter Version: 8.6
Python Version: Python 3.10.11
Operating System: macOS Sonoma (14.1.1 (23B81))
MacBook Pro Model: 16-inch MacBook Pro (Intel i7)

**Problem Description:**
I have a Tkinter game, which is a Space Invader-like game. When I run it on my internal (Retina display: 60Hz), on my MacBook Pro, I experience noticeable lag (everything is slower, and my supposition is NSHighResolutionCapable set to True). However, when I switch to an external display (basic 1080p 60Hz), the lag disappears.

I tried using `tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 2)` on my canvas and my frame but none works.

My game structure looks like this (but I don't think it's necessary) :

```
class GameView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(background='black')
        self.pack()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=800, height=600, bg='black')
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Assets
        background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/images/background.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=background_image)
        self.canvas.image = background_image
        self.player_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/images/player.png")
        self.invaders_images = [
            tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/images/invader-yellow.png"),
            tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/images/invader-green.png"),
            tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/images/invader-red.png"),
        ]

        # Entities
        self.invaders = []
        self.bullets = []
        self.protections = []
        self.bombs = []

        # Direction (left, right, down)
        self.direction = 1
        self.move_down = 0

        # Invaders
        for row, y in enumerate(range(50, 250, 60)):
            for x in range(0, 700, 90):
                self.invaders.append(self.create_invader(x, y, self.invaders_images[row % len(self.invaders_images)]))

        # Player
        self.player = self.create_player(400, 500)

        # Protections
        for x in range(140, 800, 220):
            self.protections.append(self.create_protection(x, 450))
            self.protections.append(self.create_protection(x, 420))

        self.after(20, self.move_invaders)

        # Drop bomb each 2 seconds
        self.after(2000, self.drop_bomb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by modifying this file : `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Resources/Python.app/Contents/Info.plist`

And by changing the line from :

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<true/>
```

to :

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<false/>
```